# Error in creating trigger

Tags: mysql, database-design, trigger

I have 4 tables:

**`event`:**
`event_id(p.k) | uid | circle_id(f.k)`

**`activity`:**
`uid | performed_activity_id(f.k->event_id) | activity_type_id`

**`follow`:**
`follower_id | circle_id(f.k)`

**`notification`:**
`sender_id | receiver_id(follower_id of follow table)`

I want to create a trigger which inserts values into the `activity` and `notification` tables whenever there is an entry for `event` table.
I am able to insert values into the `activity` table because it is directly connected to `event` table.

However, I am not able to insert into the `notification` table because the `receiver_id` field in the `notification` table is coming from the `follow` table which is connected to `event` table by `circle_id`.

Here I am using select in trigger which is actually wrong.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `InsertToActivity` ;

CREATE TRIGGER `InsertToActivity` AFTER INSERT ON  `event` 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
    INSERT INTO activity( uid, performed_activity_id, activity_type_id ) 
        VALUES (new.uid, new.event_id,  '1');

    select follower_id from folow where circle_id=new.circle_id;

    insert into notification_table (sender_id,object_id,receiver_id) 
        values (new.uid,new.event_id,new.follower_id);
end;
```

Is it good way to do this type of work using TRIGGERS?

Comment: Is there a `object_id` column in `notification` table?

Comment: yes there is `object_id` column which will take `event_id`

Answer (score 0):

I assume new.follower_id is supposed to be:

```
select follower_id from folow where circle_id=new.circle_id;
```

I don't think this will work. If you want to use this approach you need to declare a variable for follower_id and select into that. However, a better approach (IMO) is to do:

```
INSERT INTO activity( uid, performed_activity_id, activity_type_id ) 
    VALUES (new.uid, new.event_id,  '1');

insert into notification_table (sender_id,object_id,receiver_id)
    select new.uid ,new.event_id, follower_id 
    from folow where circle_id=new.circle_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The trigger must be created using `DELIMTER` like this

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `InsertToActivity` ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertToActivity` AFTER INSERT ON  `event` 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
    INSERT INTO activity( uid, performed_activity_id, activity_type_id ) 
        VALUES (new.uid, new.event_id,  '1');
    select follower_id INTO @fid from folow where circle_id=new.circle_id;
    insert into notification_table (sender_id,object_id,receiver_id) 
        values (new.uid,new.event_id,@fid);
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

or

```
# Code from Lenhart's Answer
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `InsertToActivity` ;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertToActivity` AFTER INSERT ON  `event` 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
    INSERT INTO activity( uid, performed_activity_id, activity_type_id ) 
        VALUES (new.uid, new.event_id,  '1');
    insert into notification_table (sender_id,object_id,receiver_id)
        select new.uid ,new.event_id, follower_id 
        from folow where circle_id=new.circle_id;
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```